# Google colab not detecting changes in .py files

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm importing a .py file in Google Colab. I do as usual, mounting Drive, inserting the directory and importing the file:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive', force_remount=True)

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/working_folder/')

import my_file
my_file.my_function()
```

Everything works fine, but when I edit the .py file by double clicking on the files section in Google Colab, the changes are not detected, I have to restart the environment. Is that normal? How can I do to detect the changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jupyter's `autoreload` magic command:

```
%load_ext autoreload 
%autoreload 2
```

before your module `import` should work (the number depending on [the mode you want](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/autoreload.html)).

I've just tried this on my Colab session and it worked.

Source: [this tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/github/bebi103a/bebi103a.github.io/blob/master/lessons/03/packages_and_modules.ipynb#scrollTo=-w5ZVuvHaHZG) and the IPython docs from the link above

Comment: Thank you, it's working great! Just to mention, you must add it before the import of your module and the first time you must restart the kernel.